# Unexpected indefinite integration result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider following expression:
$\int_0^1 \sqrt{4194 x^4-6804 x^3+3960 x^2-972 x+90} \, dx$

If i use N[] to calculate it, i get following result:

$N\left[\int_0^1 \sqrt{4194 x^4-6804 x^3+3960 x^2-972 x+90} \, dx,25\right]$

```
= 6.027972711543818613109397
```

If i use NIntegrate to calculate it, i get following result:

$\text{NIntegrate}\left[\sqrt{4194 x^4-6804 x^3+3960 x^2-972 x+90},\{x,0,1\},\text{WorkingPrecision}\to 25\right]$

```
= 6.027972711543818613109397
```

But if i try to calculate indefinite integral first, and then calculate the result i get following:

```
indefiniteIntegral[x_] = Integrate[Sqrt[4194 x^4 - 6804 x^3 + 3960 x^2 - 972 x + 90], x]
```

$N[\text{indefiniteIntegral}[1]-\text{indefiniteIntegral}[0],25]$

```
= 4.435757944345431340027424 + 0.042341350166508502449667i
```

Which is clearly different...

Am i missing something?

Comment: [Of definite relevance: *Mathematica and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/). The upshot is, don't use indefinite integrals to evaluate definite integrals in a compute algebra system unless you really know what you're doing.  Even then, probably don't.

Comment: @march: Not a good advice if your goal is to find the exact solution - in that case never use numerical evaluation. Of course, it does not mean that it is always possible to express such a solution in finitely many functions.

Comment: The discontinuity of the antiderivative is a phenomenon noted in the `Integrate` reference page under Possible Issues > Indefinite Integrals

Comment: @azerbajdzan Unless there was a comment deleted, I see no advice regarding use of numeric integration. That stated, such use can be a viable way to check results.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: How you interpret "don't use indefinite integrals to evaluate definite integrals in a compute algebra system"? So how would you evaluate definite integral if you cannot use indefinite integral and cannot use numeric evaluation?

Comment: @azerbajdzan One can often evaluate a definite integral in exact terms without first evaluating an antiderivative.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Not sure if this is what you mean, but here's an example where we do not simply plug in from the antiderivative. `In[10]:= indef = Integrate[Log[x],x]                                            
Out[10]= -x + x Log[x]
In[11]:= def = Integrate[Log[x], {x,-1-I,-1+I}]                                 
         I
Out[11]= - (-4 + Pi + Log[4])
         2

In[12]:= N[def]                                                                 
Out[12]= 0. + 0.263944 I

In[13]:= N[(indef /. x->-1+I) - (indef /. x->-1-I)]                             
Out[13]= 0. - 6.01924 I`

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: You said "One can often evaluate a definite integral in exact terms without first evaluating an antiderivative.". What the connection is with your example? Do not use antiderivative and do not use numeric evaluation and compute exact value of some integral - that is what you said.

Comment: @azerbajdzan `In[169]:= ee = x^2*BesselJ[1, x]*BesselK[3, x];
Integrate[ee, x]
i1 = NIntegrate[ee, {x, 0, Infinity}]
i2 = Integrate[ee, {x, 0, Infinity}]
i1 - i2

Out[170]= \[Integral]x^2 BesselJ[1, x] BesselK[3, x] \[DifferentialD]x

Out[171]= 6.87199

Out[172]= 6 EllipticE[-1] - (7 EllipticK[-1])/2

Out[173]= -1.05072*10^-12`

Comment: @azerbajdzan To address your question further, I took the advice to mean "Don't plug endpoints into indefinite integrals and expect to get the correct corresponding definite integral".

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: But that applies also to numeric evaluation of definite integrals without using indefinite integrals. Do not expect to get correct answer if there is a branch cut. One example - numerically (without indefinite integral) compute contour integral along closed loop and you should get zero according to Cauchy's integral theorem, but if the function has a branch cut in the region you will not get zero, hence you get a "wrong" numerical evaluation.

Comment: @azerbajdzan I'm not sure what you are claiming. I can take a function with a branch cut and integrate around a contour that hits that branch cut. This will not in general give zero. But why does the Cauchy theorem say it should? That's sort of the point of branch points and cuts: one cannot make a continuous antiderivative along the full path. If your function is `1/z` then you are in this situation. And in this case CIF says you do not get zero.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Sqrt[z] has no poles so according Cauchy's integral formula you should get zero along any closed loop. You can verify by NIntegrate[Sqrt[z], {z, 1 - I, 2 - I, 2 + I, 1 + I, 1 - I}]. Then you can try NIntegrate[Sqrt[z], {z, -1 - I, -2 - I, -2 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I}] but you get "wrong" result "2.4379*I". Indeed it is wrong result because Cauchy's integral formula must hold. What is wrong is that Sqrt[z] has branch cut in the region and you have to redefine Sqrt[z] in a such way that you avoid branch cut in the region... then you get zero also in the second region.

Comment: @azerbajdzan There is a difference between "a square root of `z` that is analytic in the region in question" (which exists, and to which CIF would apply) and "the single-valued function `Sqrt[z]` on that same region". CIF does not apply to the latter.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Square root is multi-valued function and can be defined as single-valued with branch cut wherever you want - along negative real axis, along positive real axis... you should always use such definition that has no branch cut in region of your interest then CIF will hold everywhere you want. By that way this is exactly what happened in OP problem - but it should be possible to move branch cut of antiderivative outside the region of interest and then integral would be computed correctly even with indefinite integral.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: The following definition of `sqrt` is as valid as regular Mathematica definition: `Sqrt[Abs[z]]*Exp[I*(Mod[Arg[z] + \[Pi]/2, 2*\[Pi]] - \[Pi]/2)/2]`. If you integrate it over the second region in my post above you get zero as CIF says. `NIntegrate[Sqrt[Abs[z]]*Exp[I*(Mod[Arg[z] + \[Pi]/2, 2*\[Pi]] - \[Pi]/2)/2], {z, -1 - I, -2 - I, -2 + I, -1 + I, -1 - I}]`

Comment: @azerbajdzan I trust you understand that your latest comments do not pertain the the WL function `Sqrt[z]`. That stated I have no disagreement with those comments.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Mathematica's `Sqrt` do not represent the "whole nature" of square root as a multi-valued function. And solving math problems ALWAYS pertain the real multi-valued `sqrt` function not the `Sqrt` function of Mathematica. Integrating `Sqrt[something]` over region where there is a discontinuity rarely has any mathematical sense, maybe I should say it never has any mathematical sense. But I do not blame Mathematica it is property of all such software when dealing with multi-valued functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integrand is continuous, but Mathematica's anti-derivative is not. This is why you can't use the anti-derivative to evaluate the definite integral between the limits.

```
integrand = Sqrt[4194 x^4 - 6804 x^3 + 3960 x^2 - 972 x + 90];
FunctionContinuous[integrand, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[integrand, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But look at the anti-derivative

```
indefiniteIntegral[x_] =   Integrate[integrand], x];
ReImPlot [indefiniteIntegral[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also

```
 FunctionContinuous[indefiniteIntegral[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Since your integrand is continuous at each point between $x=0,x=1$, then <s>the anti-derivative should be differentiable at each one of these points as well</s>  there exists an antiderivative that is continuous between these points. The antiderivative given here does not have this property.

Answer (score 6):

Read [EllipticPi](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/language/v13/ref/EllipticPi.html.en) about its branch cut discontinuities in "Details" section.

I identified the exact position of point of discontinuity to be (around 0.607405):

```
Root[-7 + 62 x - 162 x^2 + 122 x^3 + 13 x^4, 4]
```

So you can evaluate the integral in two parts: first from `0` to discontinuity point and second from discontinuity point to `1` like so:

```
int = Integrate[(4194 x^4 - 6804 x^3 + 3960 x^2 - 972 x + 90)^(1/2), x];
root = Root[-7 + 62 x - 162 x^2 + 122 x^3 + 13 x^4, 4];
(int /. x -> root - 10^-25) - (int /. x -> 0) + (int /. 
    x -> 1) - (int /. x -> root + 10^-25);
N[%, 25]
    
(* 6.027972711543818613109397 + 0.*10^-25 I *)
```

It is the exact same number you got by `NIntegrate`.

Comment: Mmmm, brunch cut.

Comment: Not really. I think that is just bad antiderivative.

Comment: If you take the derivative, you get the original function back.

Comment: Not bad so much as occasionally naughty.

Comment: Nice analysis (and upvoted). `Integrate` does not manage to find this root (it times out in various attempts). If found, it is not clear that `Limit` would get the correct values approaching from opposite sides. I've seen at least one bug report where this in fact is the failure cause, in a case where `Integrate` did manage to locate the pach singularity for an antiderivative containing an elliptic.